# Not able to read newly written image

Tags: python, python-3.x, object-detection

I was actually trying to do read an image, do object detection on it and write a new image that has detected objects marked in it. A new image does indeed get saved in the working directory but I am unable to open it using cv2 or using any of the image displaying softwares on fedora.
i tried uploading it to a photo uploading site and it displays properly.
I did go through the stack overflow, they say the issue was regarding trying to read a png image using a jpeg reader and as per what i could understand i tried installing libpng but still does not work.Would be grateful if someone could help me with it.
Here is the code I have tried:

```
from imageai.Detection import ObjectDetection
import os
import cv2

execution_path = os.getcwd()

detector = ObjectDetection()
detector.setModelTypeAsRetinaNet()
detector.setModelPath( os.path.join(execution_path , "resnet50_coco_best_v2.0.1.h5"))
detector.loadModel()
detections = detector.detectObjectsFromImage(input_image=os.path.join(execution_path , "car.jpg"), output_image_path=os.path.join(execution_path , "imagenew.jpg"))

for eachObject in detections:
    print(eachObject["name"] + " : " + eachObject["percentage_probability"] )
print(cv2.imshow('detected',imagenew))
```

Comment: Note I have solved the issue by modifying the extension of the output file to be saved with.png extension instead of .jpg. So the modified code on line 11 becomes: detections = detector.detectObjectsFromImage(input_image=os.path.join(execution_path , "car.jpg"), output_image_path=os.path.join(execution_path , "imagenew.png"))

Comment: i want to do the same, but i am unable to import `from imageai.Detection import ObjectDetection` any idea what i need to install for Linux platform.